# Placeholder Script for IE9 not working by default. But working after leave the input

Tags: javascript, jquery

For IE 9 browser I m enabling placeholder text for inputs. When page landed it doesn't showing the placeholder text. But it works after i leave the input. I a missing something.

Can you help me

My Script is

```
// Initialize inline labels for IE
 if ($.browser.msie)
 {
    alert('i m iE')
  $("input[name='firstname']").each(function() {
   $(this).addClass("inlineLabel");
  });
  $("input[name='lastname']").each(function() {
   $(this).addClass("inlineLabel");
  });
  $("input[name='email']").each(function() {
   $(this).addClass("inlineLabel");
  });
  $("input[name='address']").each(function() {
   $(this).addClass("inlineLabel");
  });
  $("input[name='dayphone']").each(function() {
   $(this).addClass("inlineLabel");
  });
  $("input[name='zip']").each(function() {
   $(this).addClass("inlineLabel");
  });
  $("input[name='city_temp']").each(function() {
   $(this).addClass("inlineLabel");
  });
  initLabels();
 }

 // Inline labels
 function initLabels() {
    $("input.inlineLabel").each(function() {
        var l = $(this).attr("placeholder");
        this.value = l;
        $(this).addClass('unfilled');
    });
    $('input.inlineLabel').focus(function() {
        var l = $(this).attr("placeholder");
        if (this.value == l)
            $(this).val('').removeClass('unfilled');
    });
    $('input.inlineLabel').blur(function() {
        var l = $(this).attr("placeholder");
        if (this.value == '') {
            this.value = l;
            $(this).addClass('unfilled');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing `this.value` with `$(this).val()` to get the input value, and `$(this).val(your_value)` to set, like you already do